# Django rest_framework custom errror handler

Tags: python, django, error-handling

I want to write django custom error handler as in flask custom error handler .
Suppose i have 100 api's which gets the same error everytime let's say

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError
```

Sample code

```
def post(self, request):
    if not request: return Response({"message": "Please enter credentials"})
    input_param = json.load(request)
    print(input_param)
    return "something"
```

The above code will return **json.decoder.JSONDecodeError** if no params are passed in post request .

In flask this can be handled by writing custom error handler like

```
@app.errorhandler(json.decoder.JSONDecodeError)
def handle_marshmallow_validaton_errors(err):
    
    return jsonify({"error": "Bad request"}), 400
```

In django is there any way we can write custom error handlers

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use DRF custom exception handler https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling.
you can use it to check the spawn exception and return a proper response.